# PHP time() to Date/Time returning strange results

Tags: php

I have a database field called last_hit which as you can guess stores the time of the users last hit/action. Now it is all working fine except when I output that time in a specific format. The first piece of code shows you how I am formatting the results and displaying them. The next piece of code shows you the updating of the last hit field.

// Display code here

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Last Action</strong>: <?=date("d/m/Y h:m:s A", $userResults->last_hit)?>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

// Update code here

```
        $updateDate = array($time, $userID);

        $updateLastHitSQL = "UPDATE `users` SET last_hit = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
        $db->prepare($updateLastHitSQL)->bind(2, $updateDate, true)->execute();
```

The issue I'm having is that the output is looping the time (minutes). So for instance take the time shown below as an example:

**Last Action: 09/11/2014 11:11:19 PM**

The seconds at the end update correctly, that is until it reaches 59 and instead of the minutes field going to 12 it stays 11 and the seconds just change to 0. So no time is actually being updated except the seconds. Yet when I look in the database the last_hit field is being added on to every page update as expected to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your date format string. "d/m/Y H:m:s" should be "d/m/Y H:i:s". 'm' is for months, 'i' is for minutes.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Oh dyam, I've been stupid in my formatting... Thanks a million buddy.